# How to get a path variable in a text file by using FOR in a Windows batch file?

Tags: string, windows, batch-file

I try to retrieve a path in a text file identified by a tag.

I have a line like that in my text file:

```
"mypath":"C:\myfolder"
```

I need to retrieve the path corresponding to `mypath` tag.

I tried this:

```
for /f tokens^=2^,3^ delims^=^"^:^" %%a in ('type %mytextfile%^|find """mypath"""') do (  
    echo %%a 
    echo %%b
)
```

But it doesn't work, the result is:

```
mypath
C
```

So my problem probably comes from the colon character that is used in the delimiter and in the string I want to get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two points: First, just use quotes for the `for` options instead of escaping everything. Second, you can add a `*` after a tokens option to imply that no more tokenizing should be done and the rest should be returned as a single token:

```
for /f "tokens=1* delims=:" %%A in ('findstr /b /c:"""mypath""" %mytextfile%') do (
  echo %%~A
  echo %%~B
)
```

A few more things:

- There's no need for `type` when the command you're piping to can read files just fine. :-)
- `findstr /b` matches the search string at the beginning of the line, as an added check that you've really got the correct line.
- The `~` for printing the variables just eliminates the quotes around the text, so you don't have to deal with them anymore.

Comment: OMG, thank you very much for that perfectly detailed answer ! It works fine and my code is now much cleaner :)